# Simple parser with regular expression

Tags: c++, parsing, regex

If I draw something in Illustrator and extract it with AI2Canvas I want it to be customizable so I wrote this simple program. It adds two variables: one to resize and one to shift the path coordinate.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string path = argv[1];
  std::ifstream input(path);

  std::size_t found_name = path.find_last_of("/\\");
  std::size_t found_extension = path.find_last_of(".");
  const int steps = found_extension - found_name - 1;
  std::ofstream output(path.substr(found_name + 1, steps) + ".txt");

  std::regex pattern("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?), (\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)");
  std::string in;
  while (!input.eof()) {
    std::getline(input, in);
    output << std::regex_replace(in, pattern, "($1 * resize.x) + pos.x, ($3 * resize.y) + pos.y")
           << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Test file Raw: https://pastebin.com/fDh9qbd8

Test file Resolved: https://pastebin.com/R2gpXD8Q

Comment: Instead of modifying each pair of coordinates, you could also insert a single [`ctx.translate` and `ctx.rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations) before the drawing commands.

Comment: *“Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.”*  — Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall, good code. There is a trap code fell into though.

```
while (!input.eof())
```

One of the frequently encountered problems with `iostream`s. Check the output if it has one extra newline. I'm sure you'll find it. `intput.eof()` is true when `EOF` *is* read, not before it.

Instead, use `stream >> variable` as a condition or the function that behaves like that. The expression returns a reference to stream itself, *but* the stream is convertible to `bool` to see if some failure occured. Basically, the expression above is all these steps:

1. Try to read.
2. Set failure flags if error encountered
3. Return the status

Put in a condition, it is the exact combination one needs to perform more or less controlled input. One needs to check if the read succeeded before doing anything. Some other functions in standard library behave like `operator>>`, `std::getline()` included.

As a result of above, the first line of the loop would just become a condition, and everything else intact.

```
while (std::getline(input, in)) {
    output << std::regex_replace(in, pattern, "($1 * resize.x) + pos.x, ($3 * resize.y) + pos.y")
       << '\n';
}
```

---

Smaller things follow.

Usage message would be nice. Usually frequently used utilities are put away from the code. Though in case of single argument programs it might not be much of a problem.

```
std::ofstream output(path.substr(found_name + 1, steps) + ".txt");
```

Is a little bit alerting. Since this is end user program (e.g. for a human), they might get something wrong.

Some missing `const`s here and there.

`return 0` is redundant.

Comment: I don't have much experience with regex, but it looks correct and seem to run correctly too. I hope I didn't miss the elephant in the room.

Comment: @RolandIllig, I guess I amended my post just before you posted the comment :) I added more words into the sentence about `operator>>`. I just wanted to base my explanation off of `operator>>`, then build from there.

Comment: How about `while (input.good() && std::getline(input, line)) {}`?

Comment: Regarding the regex it probably could be simplified to `([0-9.]+), ([0-9.]+)`

Comment: @yuri, it seems like `operator bool` is a superset of `good()` ([1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), [2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail), [3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good)). They have different tables, look at the first link. Thus `good()` is redundant. I could perform parsing of standard, but that will take more than a day :)

Comment: @yuri, actually, giving it another thought, the expression relies on evaluation order. I don't know if C++17 defined the order now, but I think no. Also, the good has to be to the right if check after the read is needed. The result will be correct anyway, though. About the style, my colleague from lab likes the good version too. I guess it is more about visual style.

Comment: @Incomputable  `&&` forces left-to-write short-circuiting evaluation.  It is not necessary though since the stream functions all fail themselves if the stream is in a bad state.

Comment: @yuri You can use specials in the range too, so just `[\d.]` not `[0-9.]`  But it’s not the same, since he wants only one `.` allowed!

Answer (score 2):

a short tip:  use [Raw strings](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string) to avoid the nested escapes.

Use `auto` (almost everywhere).

```
const int steps = found_extension - found_name - 1;
```

and by using `auto` you won’t have this unsigned to signed implicit conversion cluttering up your warnings window.  You do compile without generating warnings, right?

Comment: Yes, I do compile without warnings. I come back to cpp after 4 month, I started learning JavaScript in the meanwhile, so when I was declearing that variable I just put const, than the compiler droped an error and I realize that I was writing cpp, so I added int and left It has It is... Sad story